# Shiny server cannot find default css and js files of shiny

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

I recently tried to deploy a shiny app on an EC2 instance but when I accessed the page `IP-address:3838/app-name`, I got a list of `404 errors` in console for default css and js files of shiny such as shiny.css, shiny.min.js as well as default bootstrap and jquery files. Please find below the screenshot:

[image]

So at the moment, when I access the link above, I have most of UI elements visible on the page, in non-bootstrap style, but not functionable as it does locally.

I think I have all required packages installed properly as I encountered errors of missing packages at the beginning but was able to install them and reach this far in deploying the app. I'm just thinking if I'm missing some packages or if I need to configure somewhere. Have been trying to google for few hours but no success so far.

In order to make sure that the error does not come from the code I wrote, I configured to enable the default hello-world app in `/srv/shiny-server/sample-apps/hello` but still having the same issue. So I guess the error may not be from the source code but from the configurations.

Here is the log that I have for the latest request to the site:

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:34080
>
> Attaching package: ‘dplyr’
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:
>
> filter, lag
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
>
> intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
>
> Loading required package: DBI
>
> Execution halted